# what environment variables are neede for a segger project tio run?

Tags: embedded, segger-jlink

I've never worked with segger before and have been asked to get code from git-lab build-able after building the project it says the build failed with the following errors:

```
1> C:\Users\devuser\Documents\SG105\application\project\ses>mergehex -m .\Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe\temp.hex .\Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe\SG101v3_Debug+bl_settings.hex -o .\Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe\SG101v3_Debug_production.hex 

1> Parsing input hex files.

1> ERROR: One of the files to merge cannot be found.
Build failed
```

how do I fix this? is there a path that needs to be pointed to somewhere?

Comment: Segger is the name of a company, not a specific product.  You need to be more specific.  That said, clearly here you are using a tool called mergehex which may or may not be Segger specific, but its purpose is perhaps implicit.  Clearly one of the three hex files you are attempting to merge does not exist.  You could simply look in `Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe\` to wee which.  It is likely that it is an issue with the project rather than the Segger tool.  Quite possibly there was an earlier error message indicating why the missing component was not built.

Comment: It is also an XY problem as stated - you are asking about environment variables and presupposing that that is the problem.  That is not indicated by the error message; start with why the files either do not exist or why the relative path `Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe` is not correct.

Comment: mergehex is an executable and I think the compiler (segger enbedded studio. my apologies I didn't realise it was the company name and not the name of the software) is looking for it in my local path.. the missing hex files are in the output folder meaning it is auto generated by the compiler.

Comment: Segger Embedded Studio is and IDE not a compiler either.  For most tools compilation does not generate hex files directly, that is normally done by a utility such as objcopy or srec.

Comment: Re. _"missing hex files are in the output folder"_ they are either _missing_ or _in the folder_, not both.  If they exist then the working directory is not correct for the relative path, if they are missing then an earlier step has failed or not been executed.  The error indicates missing _input_ files, the log of the complete build (from a "rebuild all") is what anyone would need to see to see how/where/if the files were generated.  The fragment you have posted tells little of much diagnostic use other than one or more of the files are missing or not at `.\Output\SG101v3\Debug\Exe\` .

Comment: I see. Like I said I've never done this before so I'm going in completely blind.  'arm-none-eabi-objcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  is the error I that's causing the others I think, but i do have the executable in my program files should I then add this to the path?

Comment: So you need to update your question to include the relevant information rather then mention it in a comment.  We can only address the _question_ in an answer, not the comments.  objcopy is part of GNU binutils, and should have been installed with the toolchain.